# how to make multi extension in vba inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make it multi-extension because the vba code below only has the "jpg" extension. Please recommend the solution.

Thanks

```
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fldr.Show
    f = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
    f = f & "\"
    ibox = InputBox("File Must Contain (Note * wildcards can be used)", , "*.jpg*")
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve - after the user has selected any item, you want to add a "custom" extensions to the selected item?

Comment: @Sythr , 
the selected item is only for path and I use "wscript.shell" to export list path to excel so i don't change one by one extension in the inputbox if i use multi extension

Comment: makes sense, it's a folder picker .. sorry - pretty early over here. But then I still don't really get what you are trying to do with the extension - you want to read all files with entered extensions?

Comment: @Sythr , Yes that's right I want to read all files with the extension